# DataTables manually set pagination after ajax data load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Using DataTables with `"paging": true` after ajax call data is loaded but it always start on page 1. Need to change it to a different page depending what is in the URL. Can't figure out where to put the value, was thinking here:

```
              "ajax": {
                "url": "myList",
                "type": "post",
                "data": function (d) {
                    // => HERE <=
                    return d;
                },
```

Not sure if that is a good idea, also can't seems to find a way to change a page. Basically, once the data is loaded need to somehow switch in pagination page number to let's say page 5. If there is a message Processing ... that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, you want to be able to set the start page when the table is initialized (i.e. the page reloaded), is that correct? This can be done using this parameter: [iDisplayStart](http://datatables.net/usage/options#iDisplayStart).

Furthermore, there is a plug-in API function which can be used to change the display start point after initialisation: [fnDisplayStart](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnDisplayStart)

you can refer to this link for more info: [How to set current page?](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4611/how-to-set-current-page-when-using-server-side-processing)

Moreover, I would like to know more about your specific scenario to make datatable better.

Comment: Okay I am using "iDisplayStart" : pageNumberFromUrl(), that works but only when table is initialized I need an example of how to set page after sorting?

Comment: have you tried `bResetDisplay = false` ? and generally after sorting people like to go on page 1, because you are not sure on which page your desired result is. can also try `dataTable.fnPageChange( 10 );`

Comment: I need to use fnDisplayStart to set the page number (I have the page number) after all the data is loaded.

Comment: when I try to use dataTable.fnPageChange( 0 ) keep getting Uncaught TypeError: table.fnPageChange is not a function. Is this like a separate javascript  (.js file I need to add)?